# Creating a SOAP webservice from a wsdl using groovy

Tags: web-services, grails, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl file. And I wish to create web service from this wsdl file via Grails.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, it's "Grails", not "Groovy on Grails". See http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1213

The [cxf-client plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cxf-client) uses Apache CXF and has a ton of features. It's easy to use and has a wsdl2java script that you can use to generate client code.